# DNS fail on Google Search Console

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I've some domais that are hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Despite the fact that the doman are reacheable (https://localfitness.com.br) by the browser, when I try and ping tool the results are always the same. I receive an 500 error event with Google Search Console that cannot index the site. I guess that is an DNS error. How could I debug that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools you can use to debug DNS:

- dig (my favorite)
- Google DNS Toolbox Dig [1]
- hostname
- nslookup

[1] https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Comment: If you use `dig`,  you do not need `hostname` nor `nslookup` that are far inferior and should be forgotten. Online you can use the Zonemaster and DNSviz tools.